# jstree open_all event fires twice

Tags: jquery, jstree

One of my requirements is to load(via ajax on demand) all child nodes of the node selected on jstree and return all the anchor element ids of the leaf nodes under it. I am able to do this by passing the selected node to open_all method and in the open_all event I am return the ids of lead nodes. However, my problem is when the selected is a non-leaf node other than root, the open_all event fires twice. It works fine if the selected node is root or leaf. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$tree
    .bind("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) {
        //alert("Tree loaded");
    })
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {            
        data.inst.open_all(data.rslt.obj, true);
    })
    .bind("check_node.jstree", function(event, data) { 
        //checkboxes are enabled on some pages
        data.inst.open_all(data.rslt.obj, true);
    })
    .bind("open_all.jstree", function(event, data) {
      //get all ids of leaf nodes under selected node if selected node is 
      //non-leaf node. If selected node is a leaf node return it's id.

      //alert(leaf_ids); 

      //**Here is my problem:** The alert box pops up twice if 
      //open_all was passed a non-leaf node other than root.The first time 
      //ids are empty but the second time I see the ids.           
    })
    .jstree({
        "plugins": plugins_include,
        "core": core_options,
        "html_data": html_data,
        "themes": {
            "theme": "classic",
            "dots": false,
            "icons": false
        },
        "strings": { loading: "Loading..." },
        "checkbox": {
            "override_ui": true
        },
        "ui": { "select_multiple_modifier": false }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a deeper reason why you are binding using open_all, but open_node is also an option.

```
.bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    var node = $(data.rslt.obj);
    var nodeID = node.attr('id');

    var children = $.jstree._reference(node)._get_children(node);
    if (children.length==0){
    // Dynamically load node since it has nothing loaded yet
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the jstree plugin's open_all method to fix my problem.

I added one more condition to the last line of open_all function: this.is_open(original_obj)

// so that callback is fired AFTER all nodes are open
                    if (**this.is_open(original_obj) &&** original_obj.find('li.jstree-closed').length === 0) { this.__callback({ "obj": original_obj }); }

The alert box stopped popping up twice as soon I made this change.